# Java - Memory Implementation

Tags: java

```
class Memory{
    private int[] memoryArray;
    private int size;
    public Memory(int n)
    {size = n;
        memoryArray = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            memoryArray[i] = -1;
    }
    public void write (int loc,int val)
    {if (loc >=0 && loc < size)
            memoryArray[loc] = val;
        else
            System.out.println("index out of range");
    }
    public int read (int loc)
    {return memoryArray[loc];
    }
```

}

Here is my program to test it...

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Memory mymem = new Memory(100);
        mymem.write(98 , 4);
        int x;
        x = mymem.read(98);
        System.out.println(mymem);
        mymem.dump();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            if(i%10==0)
                System.out.println(memoryArray[i]);
                                   else
                                       System.out.println(memoryArray[i]);
                                   }
    }
```

So when I type in java Memory to run it I get an error saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:main and when I run java Test it outputs Memory@9931f5....How can I fix this?

Comment: the code as it is won't compile, so I'm not sure how you get any output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Memory` class does not have a `main()` method.

You probably want to type `java Test`.

Regarding your other problem, `memoryArray` isn't visible from your `Test` class. And `Memory` doesn't have a `dump` method.

Comment: And "Memory@9931f5" is the standard format produced by Object.toString() as invoked by the System.out.println(mymem) call.

Comment: (`java.util.Arrays.toString` will be the method you want for a sensible output from the actual array (otherwise will have nonsesne starting with '[').)